# How do I change ImmutableSet from guava collections?

Tags: java, collections, guava, immutability

I have an instance of ImmutableSet. Now I need new instance containing all elements from that set except one. Something like

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> numbers = ImmutableSet.of(2, 3, 4, 5);
ImmutableSet<Integer> primeNumbers = numbers.remove(4);
```

But this code of course doesn't even compile. The only way I can do it is:

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> numbers = ImmutableSet.of(2, 3, 4, 5);
ImmutableSet.Builder<Integer> primeNumbersBuilder = new ImmutableSet.Builder<>();
for (Integer number : numbers) {
    if (number != 4) {
        primeNumbersBuilder.add(number);
    }
}
ImmutableSet<Integer> primeNumbers = primeNumbersBuilder.build();
```

But this looks quite ugly and probably isn't as efficient as could be.

All immutable collections I've seen in other languages usually provide a way to do mutable operations, returning new instances. Does guava have this functionality?

Comment: you can't change it, thats why its called [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Comment: Immutable collections might allow changing their contens, returning new objects with new contents. Check out Scala immutable collections, for example. But Guava doesn't have this functionality, probably because ImmutableXXX collections build for different purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The factory methods and `builder()` are the only additions to the `Collection` implementation in Guava, as you've probably seen in the Javadoc.

An alternative, more fluent solution to the other ones given is to use `FluentIterable`:

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> primeNumbers = FluentIterable.from(numbers)
        .filter(Predicates.not(Predicates.equalTo(4)))
        .toSet();
```

or, with static imports:

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> primeNumbers = FluentIterable.from(numbers)
        .filter(not(equalTo(4)))
        .toSet();
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted (I wanted plain add/remove methods with efficient implementation without copying entire collections), but according to https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#Persistent_mutable_collections/mutation_methods_on_immutable_col guava just doesn't support those use-cases.

Answer (score 6):

You get compilation error because `numbers.remove` method return you boolean value. Btw [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) wont allow you to add or remove the elements from Immutable set as the name suggests.

You could do the following operation like:

```
 numbers = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Sets.difference(numbers, ImmutableSet.of(4)); its like set1-set2 and creating new numbers after removing 4.
 Output
 [2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your resulting set need to be an ImmutableSet or just a plain Set?

Guava has built in functionality for filtering, just not where you think it might be

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> numbers = ImmutableSet.of(2, 3, 4, 5);
ImmutableSet filtered = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Sets.filter(orig, new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Integer input) {
        return input != 4;
    }
}));
System.out.println(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get a Set from an ImmutableSet is this:

```
Set<someClass> myMutableSet = Sets.newHashSet(someImmutableSet);
```

https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet(E...)